H.265 Image Sequence to H.264 Video
I made an image sequence of 100 png files from a H.265 video, and now I want to make a H.264 video out of those frames without losing quality. How do I do that?
I would try inserting something like -qp 0 or -crf 0 but I'm worried that it will make a larger file than the input sequence. Are there other ways to do this?
